# MySQL - Different WHERE clauses to same column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, case

I have a situation where I need to create columns depending on their content.

For instance, here is SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ec7a/1.

I need to get a result like this:

```
--------------------------
| CITY | MALES | FEMALES |
--------------------------
| NY   | 5     | 2       |
--------------------------
| DC   | 2     | 1       |
--------------------------
```

How do I go about this?

I'm looking at `CASE WHEN` statements and `IF` statements from the MySQL Manual, but a clearer explanation would be very useful.

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need `CASE`!

```
SELECT
    city,
    sum(gender = 'm') as males,
    sum(gender = 'f') as females
FROM Population
group by city
```

See this [working in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ec7a/2).

The reason this works is that in mysql, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so summing a condition counts how many times it was true!

For (most?) other databases, you must use the boring case inside the sum: `sum(case when gender = 'm' then 1 else 0 end)` etc

This type of data layout is called a ["pivot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table). Some databases, like Oracle, support it natively through specific extensions to its flavour of SQL, but in mysql you have to "roll your own".

Comment: thanks for showing equivalent for case . Won't be requiring to study case for  current work i am doing... +1

Comment: @mhasan no. you must use `sum(case when gender = 'm' then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: @Bohemian: Well this is just perfect! Your explanation about the `1` and `0` values really helped here.

Comment: @Bohemian: As an extension to my question, how would you modify the `sum` part if males are denoted by either `'m' or 'M' or 'Male'`?

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari it would be more elegant and efficient to use `IN`: `sum(gender in ('m', 'M'))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CITY,
        SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MALE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FEMALE
FROM Population
GROUP BY City
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ec7a/6)

You can also do prepared statement

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = ''',
      GENDER,
      ''' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS ',
      GENDER
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Population;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  CITY, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM Population
                    GROUP BY City');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ec7a/15)

Comment: @Bohemian yep, you're right that's why I upvoted your answer :D